# Translate constants.js file using i18next

Tags: reactjs, translate, i18next, react-i18next

im trying to translate the constants.js file with i18next library but im failing to do so.
I've read that it has something to do with interpolation but im not sure. Ive already created the global.json file

```
{
"header": {
    "hello-world" : "hello"
}
```

}

here is my code in the constants.js

```
`import i18next from 'i18next';

const desktopTabs = [
    label: i18next.t('header.hello-world'),
  }
]

export {
  desktopTabs
};`
```

But this didnt work it shows 'header.hello-world' in a string.
can anyone help?
thanks!

Comment: There is something broken in the bracket structure of `constant.js`. Please edit your question. Additionally you please use triple-backtick markups for your code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure i18next is initialized before calling the t function.
Set the debug flag to true to see the log warnings.

Comment: thanks for your answer. for that I would have to turn constant.js into a functional component? I want to leave it as it is or is it not possible?

Comment: i18next needs to be initialized before calling t() this is hiw it works… there’s no way to change that